# Adding Virtual Keybord in C#.Net Application

Tags: c#, keyboard, virtual

I am developing one application, where i need to show one virtual keyboard, and add the text in a field, and also in different language, like Punjabi and Hindi. Can anyone tell me the way I can do this. for reference, check the link,
http://shriwaheguru.com/punjabi_keyboard.html.

I tried to import .dll file for Punjabi and Hindi in my program, but couldn't find the way I can use it in virtual keyboard.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Windows version and environment you're targeting, you may use the onscreen keyboard, which does offer support for Punjabi - and I suppose Hindi as well.

You can start its process like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

If necessary you can set its size and position, as well as destroy its borders, via p/invoke.

Now, if you're talking about a web implementation, that's a completely different animal.

Comment: Is there anyway i can use, UNICODE, for this, so that it will work on all system.

Comment: the above solution is also valid, and appreciate that, but is there any way that i can set it only for a particular language, like, English only, or Punjabi only or Hindi Only.

Comment: I believe you can - The keyboard support dynamic language change via alt-shift, so you can use SendKeys.Send() to set it programatically.

Comment: I am using SendKeys.Send("%+"); for {Alt Shift} when I activate osk.exe...and same when i close it, but it is not working. Please help